# Dart: convert Map to JSON with all elements quoted

Tags: json, spring-mvc, dart, jackson

I'm serializing a form in Dart into JSON then posting it to a Spring MVC backend using Jackson to deserialize the JSON.

In dart, if I print out the JSON, I'm getting:

```
{firstName: piet, lastName: venter}
```

Jackson doesn't like the data in this format, it returns a status 400 and `The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.`

If I put quotes around all the fields, Jackson accepts the data and I get a response back.

```
{"firstName": "piet", "lastName": "venter"}
```

In dart I build a `Map<String, String> data = {};` then loop through all form fields and do `data.putIfAbsent(input.name, () => input.value);`

Now when I call `data.toString()`, I get the unquoted JSON which I'm guessing is invalid JSON.

If I `import 'dart:convert' show JSON;` and try `JSON.encode(data).toString();` I get the same unquoted JSON.

Manually appending double-quotes seems to work:

```
data.putIfAbsent("\"" + input.name + "\"", () => "\"" + input.value + "\"");
```

On the Java side there's no rocket science:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/seller")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class SellerController {

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = {"Content-Type=application/json"})
    public Seller createSeller(@RequestBody Seller sellerRequest){
```

So my question, is there a less hacky way in Dart to build quoted JSON (other than manually escaping quotes and adding quotes manually) that Jackson expects?
Can Jackson be configured to allow unquoted JSON ?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

```
import 'dart:convert';
...
json.encode(data); // JSON.encode(data) in Dart 1.x
```

always resulted in quoted JSON for me.
You don't need to call `toString()`

Comment: Found the problem, JSON.encode does work. Thanks Gunter! Must be sleepiness making me miss obvious stuff.

Comment: @ChristianX `json.encode(data)` is still valid in Dart 2.x and it's equivalent to `jsonEncode(data)`

Comment: you are right with this, yet the auto import doesnt work within android studio when trying to use the json.encode(data) method. I noticed that, when I tried to implement your answer but there was no import. The auto import does work with the jsonEndcode method.

Answer (score 14):

**Simple way**

```
import 'dart:convert';
Map<String, dynamic> jsonData = {"name":"vishwajit"};
print(JsonEncoder().convert(jsonData));
```