# Dart json.encode returns json string with key values without quotes

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to convert a dictionary to json string. However I am not getting quotes around any of the strings. I am using dart 2 . Here is what I have

```
  var resBody = {};
  resBody["email"] = "employerA@gmail.com";
  resBody["password"] = "admin123";
  var user = {};
  user["user"] = resBody;
  String str = json.encode(user);
```

Output is:

```
{user: {email: employerA@gmail.com, password: admin123}}
```

I would like this to be like an actual json object

```
{"user": {"email": "employerA@gmail.com", "password: admin123"}}
```

How can I tell dart to put quotes around it ?
I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29294019/dart-convert-map-to-json-with-all-elements-quoted) thread and am doing exactly what works for the user
Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: To me this looks like you are printing `user` (the dictionary) **not** `json.encode(user)` (the actual JSON).

Comment: yes the user object has a key "user" that has the object resBody

Comment: That is not what I mean. What I mean is that you printed the dictionary, not the encoded JSON.

Comment: any suggestions on how i can fix it ?

Comment: Yes, print the encoded JSON, not unencoded dictionary :D. Please add the print statement that you used to get the output shown in your question, then I might be able to make a concrete suggestion.

Comment: ok Ill update my post

Comment: https://dartpad.dartlang.org/bca589c77b74a3290ab1ef3e246cf384

Comment: actually after doing a restart I am getting an error. Updating my code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170202/discussion-between-mistyd-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Comment: I get this same issue

Comment: I have the same problem - is there any solution?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

This is working as expected

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  var resBody = {};
  resBody["email"] = "employerA@gmail.com";
  resBody["password"] = "admin123";
  var user = {};
  user["user"] = resBody;
  String str = json.encode(user);
  print(str);
}
```

prints

```
{"user":{"email":"employerA@gmail.com","password":"admin123"}}
```

[**DartPad example**](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/bca589c77b74a3290ab1ef3e246cf384)

[or]

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  const JsonEncoder encoder = JsonEncoder.withIndent('  ');
  try {
  var resBody = {};
  resBody["email"] = "employerA@gmail.com";
  resBody["password"] = "admin123";
  var user = {};
  user["user"] = resBody;
  String str = encoder.convert(user);
  print(str);
  } catch(e) {
    print(e);
  }
}
```

which gives you the beautified output

```
{
  "user": {
    "email": "employerA@gmail.com",
    "password": "admin123"
  }
}
```

Comment: weird. it does the opposite for me. adds double quotes right away. i wanted it not to put double quotes.

Comment: You shouldn't confuse what `print(xxx)` outputs with the actual value. If you `print(someMap)` it actually prints `print(someMap.toString())` and `toString()` is what adds quotes for string keys. If you pass it as JSON, then `toString()` might not be called.

Comment: i got it to work in my test case. i had to use jsonencode for a list within a map. if its just the outer map i didnt need to jsonencode it when i passed it to http body.

Comment: As far as I remember it sends a map as form data. That might not always be what you want.

Comment: i used json.decode(res.body)) to output the repsonse body in print().

Comment: What is different about this code from the original that makes it work?

Comment: I think the problem with the question is that the output is from `print(user)` instead of `print(str)`

Comment: This is crazy!, without quote single object is created!, If there is a nested objects! my backend won't allow a thing! Thanks! G