# Add Double Quotes On Keys & Values In A JSON Format In Dart

Tags: json, flutter, dart, mobile

I have a data in a plain string format as shown below...

```
{key_string:value,key_object-1:[{key_double:99.99999999,key_float:99.99,key_datetime:2022-06-13 11:47:35},{key_long:He \"Ali\" does't like me,lng:67.1229545,key_date:2022-06-13}],key_int:999999,key_object-2:[{key_double:99.99999999,key_float:99.99,key_datetime:2022-06-13 11:47:35},{key_long:He \"Ali\" does't like me,lng:67.1229545,key_date:2022-06-13}]}
```

but I want to make it JSON readable like below...

```
{
   "key_string":"value",
   "key_object-1":[
      {
         "key_double":"99.99999999",
         "key_float":"99.99",
         "key_datetime":"2022-06-13 11:47:35"
      },
      {
         "key_long":"He \"Ali\" does't like me",
         "lng":"67.1229545",
         "key_date":"2022-06-13"
      }
   ],

   "key_int":999999,
   "key_object-2":[
      {
         "key_double":"99.99999999",
         "key_float":"99.99",
         "key_datetime":"2022-06-13 11:47:35"
      },
      {
         "key_long":"He \"Ali\" does't like me",
         "lng":"67.1229545",
         "key_date":"2022-06-13"
      }
   ]
}
```

For this purpose, I used the below code...

```
String unformatted_JSON = unformatted_JSON.replaceAllMapped(RegExp(r'\b[\w:.\/]+\b'), (match) {
return '"${match.group(0)}"';
});
print(unformatted_JSON);
```

And got the below output that is 50% correct...

```
{
   "key_string":"value",
   "key_object-1":[
      {
         "key_double":"99.99999999",
         "key_float":"99.99",
         "key_datetime":"2022"-"06"-"13" "13:00:23"   // <<-- Main Error
      },
      {
         "key_long":"He" "\"Ali\"" "does't" "like" "me",   // <<-- Error Also
         "lng":"67.1229545",
         "key_date":"2022-06-13"
      }
   ],

   "key_int":999999,
   "key_object-2":[
      {
         "key_double":"99.99999999",
         "key_float":"99.99",
         "key_datetime":"2022"-"06"-"13" "13:00:23"   // <<-- Main Error
      },
      {
         "key_long":"He" "\"Ali\"" "does't" "like" "me",   // <<-- Error Also
         "lng":"67.1229545",
         "key_date":"2022-06-13"
      }
   ]
}
```

Now what the error in RegEx to cover the remaining errors...???

Comment: How did you end up with your data string? It looks like you have tried to use `toString()` to create JSON which is not how you should do it. You should instead do json encoding as described in: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/json . You can then also use a `JsonEncoder.withIndent` to create formatted JSON.

Comment: Yes, I have the custom data that I tried to make look like JSON and successded till this end. Well its string in real also. IN short I want to make string to JSON.

Comment: You should not use `toString()` at any point to create the JSON. Please use the JSON encoder as described in the previous linked article. If you are doing that, the generated String is going to be JSON compatible.

Comment: I have the custom data not any object or array or variables etc. Custom data build in this syntax string using ' + ' operator. So only hope is to make it using Regex.

Comment: You should ask the provider of this data to generate JSON compatible strings. The current format is broken and cannot be parsed safely since there are multiple places where it is ambiguously what the data should be parsed as.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. WIll try to make it JSON as there is no provider of this data format and I created this format from myself froms multiple objects and lists. Will share the answer once found.

Comment: If your input comes from a Dart program, you need to make sure you generate the JSON using `jsonEncode` instead of trying to create it manually. Most other popular programming languages should also come with ways to generate valid JSON based on data structures.

Comment: Refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50129573/dart-json-encode-returns-json-string-with-key-values-without-quotes?rq=4)
Enjoy Coding