Serialize a map containing an object into JSON using Dart
I am using the json_serializable package in Dart to convert my objects to JSON so I can then store them in a SQLite database. I am struggling in converting one particular property on my class because it is a map, the keys of which are another object.
I have generated my .g file successfully, but when the toJson function is called I get a:

JsonUnsupportedObjectError (Converting object to an encodable object
failed _Map len:2).

Here is a screenshot of the data attempting to be encoded.

Below is my PlayerModel class (the key), which is really simple. I have already implemented / generated the toJson and fromJson methods here.
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';
import 'package:uuid/uuid.dart';

part 'player_model.g.dart';

const uuid = Uuid();

@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class PlayerModel {
  PlayerModel({
    required this.name,
  }) : id = uuid.v4();

  final String id;
  String name;

  /// Convert to [PlayerModel] from JSON
  factory PlayerModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> data) =>
      _$PlayerModelFromJson(data);

  /// Convert to JSON from [PlayerModel]
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$PlayerModelToJson(this);

  /// Convert the [PlayerModel] to a string
  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'PlayerModel{id: $id, name: $name}';
  }
}

And below is an extract from my BoardModel class and the converter functions.
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:uuid/uuid.dart';
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';
import 'package:counter/models/player_model.dart';

part 'board_model.g.dart';

const uuid = Uuid();

@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class BoardModel {
 ...
  }) : id = id ?? uuid.v4();

  final String id;
  final String name;
  @BoardDataConverter()
  final Map<PlayerModel, double> boardData; // Players and scores for the board
  final PlayerModel owner;

  /// Create a [BoardModel] from a map
  factory BoardModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> data) =>
      _$BoardModelFromJson(data);

  /// Convert the [BoardModel] to a map
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$BoardModelToJson(this);

  }
}

// TODO - Convert PlayerModel to nested JSON?
class BoardDataConverter
    implements JsonConverter<Map<PlayerModel, double>, String> {
  const BoardDataConverter();

  @override
  Map<PlayerModel, double> fromJson(String json) => jsonDecode(json);

  @override
  String toJson(Map<PlayerModel, double> data) => jsonEncode(data);
}

And finally, here is the fromJson generated function from board_model.g.dart.
BoardModel _$BoardModelFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => BoardModel(
      id: json['id'] as String?,
      name: json['name'] as String,
      boardData: const BoardDataConverter()
          .fromJson((json['boardData']) as Map<String, dynamic>),
      owner: PlayerModel.fromJson(json['owner'] as Map<String, dynamic>),
    );

The BoardDataConverter class is the work in progress. I suspect I need to somehow convert / call the toJson method on the PlayerModels in the map as part of the conversion too, but I'm not sure if that's correct or how to do that. Any help appreciated.

Could you provide an example of the file/data you are trying to parse. According to the message, your input data is not following JSON specs. The key shall be a string, and the code generated by <json_serializable> needs the json object to be a Map<String, dynamic>

@pcba-dev I have updated my question as I resolved my initial problem of the generated class file not generating (forgot to actually annotate my property with my converter function). So now everything compiles, but I get an error when the function is called in app usage.

With the screenshot it is still not clear what the source data is. Do you the string equivalente? In what format are you receiving the data? Could you check the runtimetype of the data to see what it is?

Sorry, but I'm not sure what you mean. The data is a Map of PlayerModels and doubles. Here are the values copied:
PlayerModel (PlayerModel{id: 2fc1365b-2234-49f6-a968-96b3eba11daf, name: Player 1}) -> 0.0
PlayerModel (PlayerModel{id: 50c6c7a7-7fcc-4f9a-874f-b9ed3666bf2b, name: Player 2}) -> 0.0

import 'dart:convert';

json.encode(data);

You can use this inbuilt method to convert maps to json.
Answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/29294323/23001029

I think I am already using that (just as JsonEncode(data) instead). But possibly not in the correct place or way?

Your custom converter shall extend JsonConverter, which is defined as:
abstract class JsonConverter<T, S> {
  const JsonConverter();

  T fromJson(S json);
  S toJson(T object);
}

Where "S" is the datatype you are converting from, and "T" is the datatype you are converting to.
Assuming your data is actually in JSON format, it is transmitted as a key-value map, where as per JSON specs (ECMA-404) all keys must be strings. However, it seems that it is not your case since it is an object (Map<String, dynamic>), therefore that player-model "key" will still be need to be converted in a second step from that Map into its corresponding PlayerModel object.
class BoardDataConverter implements JsonConverter<Map<PlayerModel, double>, Map<Map<String, dynamic>, dynamic>> {
  const BoardDataConverter();

  @override
  Map<PlayerModel, double> fromJson(final Map<Map<String, dynamic>, dynamic> data) {
    final Map<PlayerModel, double> result = {};
    for (final entry in data.entries) {
      // Parse the map representation of the player-model to the actual object.
      final player = PlayerModel.fromJson(entry.key as Map<String, dynamic>);
      result[player] = entry.value as double;
    }
    return result;
  }

  @override
  Map<Map<String, dynamic>, dynamic> toJson(Map<PlayerModel, double> object) {
    final Map<Map<String, dynamic>, dynamic> result = {};
    for (final entry in object.entries) {
      // Pase the player-model object to its Map representation.
      result[entry.key.toJson()] = entry.value;
    }
    return result;
  }
}

class BoardModel {
  const BoardModel({
    ...
    required this.boardData,
    ...
  });

  ...

  @BoardDataConverter()
  final Map<PlayerModel, double> boardData;

  ...

  factory BoardModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> data) => _$BoardModelFromJson(data);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$BoardModelToJson(this);
  
  ...
}


Thank you. This saves the data correctly, but when reading it / fromJson, I am getting a _TypeError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast). The specific line is in the .g generated file's fromJson method:
  boardData: const BoardDataConverter()
      .fromJson((json['boardData']) as Map<String, dynamic>),


I have updated the answer. Thank means your data is not conforming to JSON specs, since you are having a Map as a key. Anyway, based on that error I have more information on the structure of the data and I guess it should work now.

So perhaps a follow on question on best practices... should I only use the ID or Name of the PlayerModel as the Key instead then (or some other property)? Rather than parsing the whole object as JSON. What do you recommend / is best practice?

JSON standard (ECMA-404) specifies that keys must always be of type string. Apart from that, it's up to you how to define your JSON file structure. It could be just a simple map from (player) id to score, or if the PlayerModel is actually a snippet from a larger model you could include the score as another field and map the (player) id to the json-map representation of the model, or you could even have a single entry on your JSON with key "data" and as value an array of the json-map representations of those PlayerModel's which would also contain the score as a extra field.
